# Displaying JS/Ajax message after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form I'm setting up with javascript/ajax to not reload the page when a submission is successful.

The form works and it displays the success message. The problem is it doesn't display the success message in the correct div. I press submit. The success message should show up right over the form specified in `<div id=success>`. Instead it shows up at the top.

HTML CODE:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name" id="name">Name<span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" required/>
        <label for="email" id="email">Email<span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" required/>
        <label for="Message" id="message">Message<span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="success"> <span>
                    <p>Your message was sent succssfully! I will be in touch as soon as I can.</p>
                 </span>

</div>
<div id="error"> <span>
                    <p>Something went wrong, try refreshing and submitting the form again.</p>
                 </span>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
/*validate contact form*/
$(function () {
    $('#contact').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "come on, you have a name don't you?",
                minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            email: {
                required: "no email, no message"
            },
            message: {
                required: "um...yea, you have to write something to send this form.",
                minlength: "thats all? really?"
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                type: "POST",
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                url: "contact_me.php",
                success: function () {
                    $('#contact :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $('#contact').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function () {
                        $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $(this).find('label').css('cursor', 'default');
                        $('#success').fadeIn();
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#contact').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function () {
                        $('#error').fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

There is of course a lot more html code since this is being embedded on a full web page. I don't know if anything in the html code would affect it though. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "The success message should show up right over the form" Are you trying to display in a "modal" window/pop up style?

Comment: No, not a popup style. You can check out the live version here if it helps: http://www.afwebworks.com

Comment: Both your success and error messages consist of divs containing `paragraph` tags, which are block-level elements, wrapped around `span` tags, which are inline elements. This is invalid code as per the W3C standards. Try fixing your HTML see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your CSS. You have `#success span` as `position: absolute`. Remove this and it will show up in the correct location.

Comment: That easy. I appreciate the help!